# Casting static_cast on dynamically-created element of smartpointers vector

Tags: c++, casting, smart-pointers

I'm learning C++ and I'm facing a problem. I have created a vector of smartpointers containing dynamically-created objects of a derived class but I am unable to cast a static_cast on one of these objects. I have tried several approaches but it didn't work.

this is my code:

```
class Person {};
class Walker : public Person {};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>>v1;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { v1.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Person>(new Walker) ); }

//trying to cast static_cast on element on position 1:
std::unique_ptr<Person>ptr = move(v1[1]);
auto walkers = static_cast<Walker*>(ptr);//doesnt work - no suitable conversion function
```

Comment: See:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unwrap the raw pointer out of the `unique_ptr` first:

```
auto walkers = static_cast<Walker*>(ptr.get());
```

Note that the ownership of the pointer still belongs to `ptr`, which is a `std::unique_ptr<Person>` still. You can transfer the ownership like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Walker> walkers(static_cast<Walker*>(ptr.release()));
```

If you want, you can write a function like this

```
template<typename Target, typename Source>
auto static_cast_unique(std::unique_ptr<Source> ptr) {
    return std::unique_ptr<Target>(static_cast<Target*>(ptr.release()));
}
```

So you can write

```
auto walkers = static_cast_unique<Walker>(std::move(v1[1]));
```

Now, some issues with your code:

- `Person` needs a virtual destructor. You have `Walker` objects owned by `std::unique_ptr<Person>`s. That's OK in itself, but when those `unique_ptr`s try to destroy their objects, they will call `~Person`, not `~Walker` (since that is what their type says to do), and that will be UB. Give `Person` a `virtual ~Person()` (and `Walker` will inherit that `virtual`ness)

  ```
  class Person { public: virtual ~Person() = default; };
  class Walker : public Person {};
  ```
- `std::unique_ptr(new ...)` is better written with `std::make_unique`

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) v1.push_back(std::make_unique<Walker>());
  ```

  `std::unique_ptr`s will automatically upcast.
- In this case, it seems OK to use `static_cast`, because you *know* that the `Person*` you have actually points to a `Walker`. However, you will want to use `dynamic_cast` in the general case, so you can detect when the object *isn't* of the type you expect. I would use a function like this

  ```
  template<typename Target, typename Source>
  std::unique_ptr<Target> dynamic_cast_unique(std::unique_ptr<Source> &&ptr) {
      if(auto ret = dynamic_cast<Target*>(ptr.get())) {
          ptr.release();
          return std::unique_ptr<Target>(ret);
      } else return nullptr;
  }
  ```

  Which is used like

  ```
  auto walkers = dynamic_cast_unique<Walker>(std::move(v1[1]));
  ```

  If it succeeds, `walkers` will own the object previously owned by `v1[1]` and `v1[1]` will be empty. Otherwise, `walkers` will be empty and `v1[1]` will be unchanged.

Comment: i realized that creating ptr was crashing the vector. Just using std::move(v1[1]) did the job.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you want to do!

The `Person` class should have a virtual interface that `Walker` implements so you don't need to convert a Person pointer to a Walker pointer.

That being said:

To solve your current problem:

```
std::unique_ptr<Walker> getWalkerFromPerson(std::unique_ptr<Person> person)
{
    // Note there is still an issue here.
    // If this is not a Walker then it will leak
    // the person as dynamic_cast will give you a nullptr
    return std::unique_ptr<Walker>(dynamic_cast<Walker*>(person.release()));
}
```

Then call like this:

```
auto walkers = getWalkerFromPerson(std::move(v1[0]));
```

Some pointers:

1. You need to release the `person` (so it does not delete it).
2. You need to use `dynamic_cast` (to cast from parent towards an unknown (run-time known) child type).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast `std::unique_ptr`, but you can do it for its managed pointer:

```
auto* walkers = static_cast<Walker*>(ptr.get());
```